# performSelectorInBackground, notify other viewcontroller when done

Tags: iphone, multithreading

I have a method used to save an image when the user clicks Save.
I use performSelectorInBackground to save the image, the viewcontroller is popped and the previous viewcontroller is shown.

I want the table (on the previousUIViewController) to reload its data when the imagesaving is done.

How can I do this?

The save method is called like this:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(saveImage) withObject:nil];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your `saveImage` method, post a notification just after finishing saving the image and before returning from the method. Something like this:

```
// post notification
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ImageSaved" object:nil];
```

In the controller handling the table, implement

```
- (void) imageSaved:(NSNotification *)notification{

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

and in its `viewDidLoad` method add the following code to register for notifications:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                selector:@selector(imageSaved:)
                                                 name:@"ImageSaved" object:nil];
```

finally, unregister in the `dealloc` method adding

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the way to go is calling the method at the end of the saveImage routine. Maybe something like

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(saveImage) withObject:previousView];
```

And if you want to keep saveImage agnostic, create a protocol with a callback that your previousView can use.

```
@protocol processingFinishedDelegate
-(void)processingFinished;
@end
```

so At the end of saveImage you'll have:

```
[(id<processingFinishedDelegate>)object processingFinished];
```

and of course your previousView class interface should handle the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

I am having problems using this to update UITextView with the approach "unforgiven" suggested. I tried couple of different ways but all failed... I also tried notifications + observers with this but no success... Why is that? It is working fine on UILabel but no UITextView with this message:

Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...